# Does pm-powersave start automatically when running on battery?

Tags: laptop, power-management

So I just learned a bit more about pm-powersave, but couldn't find if it automatically kicks in if you're running battery power. Does somebody know if it does this? And if not, is there a way to make pm-powersave automatically activate once I am running on battery?

Comment: pm-powersave writes a log to the file`/var/log/pm-powersave.log`. What is the output of `sudo tail -f /var/log/pm-powersave.log` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not run on my system when I plug and unplug my power adapter. You can check whether it is run or not by looking at `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`. Type `tail -f /var/log/pm-powersave.log` and then plug/unplug your power adapter, it will show what scripts are run and their output. If you got nothing, then it means nothing is run.

You can create a new udev rules file to make scripts in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/` and `/etc/pm/power.d` run. As root, create `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-powersave.rules`, and put the following content into this file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/pm-powersave true"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{online}=="1", RUN+="/usr/sbin/pm-powersave false"
```

Now try to put your system into battery mode and you should be able to see output in `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`, which means the scripts have been executed.